# PHP Using file_get_contents to output remote server text file connection refused

Tags: php, ajax, ftp

I am trying to get the output of a remote server's text file to display on my website. I am using an AJAX call to call my PHP script, and in the PHP script I am using `file_get_contents` to output the text, however, it immediately says connection refused.

So my question is, what is the reason I am getting connection refused when trying to output text from my remote server?

app.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").on('click', function() {
    console.log("im in here now!");
     $.get("../lib/getoutput.php", function(data){
        console.log("Here is the output: " + data);
    });
});
});
```

getOutput.php

```
<?php //getoutput.php
    $user = 'user';
    $password = 'pass';
    $path = '/my/path';
    $gateway = '10.139.X.X';

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
        echo "get request received!";
        $report = file_get_contents("ftp://$user:$password@$gateway/$path"); 
        echo $report;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the recommended way, instead use `curl`.
If you still wants to use this function, enable few php directives: http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen